# Finding a list of adjacent words between two words

Tags: ruby, algorithm, data-structures

I am working on a programming challenge for practice and am having trouble finding a good data structure/algorithm to use to implement a solution.

**Background:**

Call two words “adjacent” if you can change one word into the other by adding, deleting, or changing a single letter.

A “word list” is an ordered list of unique words where successive words are adjacent.

**The problem:**

Write a program which takes two words as inputs and walks through the dictionary and creates a list of words between them.

**Examples:**

```
hate  → love:     hate, have, hove, love
dogs  → wolves:   dogs, does, doles, soles, solves, wolves
man   → woman:    man, ran, roan, roman, woman
flour → flower:   flour, lour, dour, doer, dower, lower, flower
```

I am not quite sure how to approach this problem, my first attempt involved creating permutations of the first word then trying to replace letters in it. My second thought was maybe something like a [suffix tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suffix_tree)

Any thoughts or ideas toward at least breaking the problem down would be appreciated. Keep in mind that this is not homework, but a programming challenge I am working on myself.

Comment: Cool problem. It's only peripherally related, but look at Levenshtein distance (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) for some inspiration. In your case, you're looking for a path through a graph whose nodes are words and edges connect words with a Levenshtein distance of 1. Probably not the data structure you're looking for, but it might provide insight.

Comment: @ChrisSchmich I had actually already looked into this, I did an implementation of the distance function to use later on in the project. The only problem is that this algorithm is not very efficient.

Comment: On the same note, this is an example implementation in case you want to look at a concrete example: https://github.com/dbalatero/levenshtein-ffi

Comment: @BobTempl I'm curious, is there an expected running time/complexity class for initial construction or performing queries?

Comment: @ChrisSchmich Not that I know of, the problem just asks for an implementation, it doesn't mention running time. I imagine that the performance of a solution for this kind of problem, wont be that efficient. Maybe I'm just being a pessimist though.

Comment: You're looking for an algorithm for Lewis Carroll's "doublets" game.  It has already been discussed http://stackoverflow.com/q/2071402/469210

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This puzzle was first stated by Charles Dodgson, who wrote *Alice's Adventures in Wonderland* under his pseudonym Lewis Carroll.

The basic idea is to create a graph structure in which the nodes are words in a dictionary and the edges connect words that are one letter apart, then do a breadth-first search through the graph, starting at the first word, until you find the second word.

I discuss this problem, and give an implementation that includes a clever algorithm for identifying "adjacent to" words, at [my blog](http://programmingpraxis.com/2009/03/20/dodgsons-doublets/).

Comment: +1. But your otherwise great blog sucks for a trivial reason: You do not introduce yourself at all. Some people are just cherrypicking for solutions to the problem, but others, when they find a great Lispy blog like yours, want to know who the heaven is behind. I was unable to find about me page at all.

Comment: @user448810 This solution only works for strings of the same length correct ?

Comment: Yes. It only works for strings of the same length. But with a different rule for "adjacent to" the same breadth-first search through a graph could be used for strings of different length.

Comment: @user448810 How exactly? The star words seem to control what adjacent-to returns. but the only star words that exist replace the letters of the regular word. `HATE = *ATE, H*TE, HA*E, HAT*e`. I tried expanding this to `HATE = *HATE, H*ATE, HA*TE, HAT*E, HATE*, *ATE, H*TE, HA*E, HAT*e` but didnt have much success. My current working solution generates all adjacent words by actually modifying the strings. The star solution is *much* cleaner though so I was hoping to adapt it.

Comment: Try a simple experiment. In your code, is HATE adjacent to HASTE? If so, breadth-first search through the graph should work. Note that the graph is much larger than with words of the same length, so it might take longer to find a solution.

Comment: @user448810 I guess I made a mistake when building my graph on the first try, thanks for your help.

Comment: I would like to see your completed solution. Perhaps you could add it here in an edit. You might also like to add a comment on my blog to show how the program can easily be extended. You might also like to put it on ideone.com with a small dictionary, so people can run it.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if this is the type of solution that you're looking for, but an active area of research is in constructing "edit distance 1" dictionaries for quickly looking up adjacent words (to use your parlance) for search term suggestions, data entry correction, and bioinformatics (e.g. finding similarities in chromosomes).  See for example [this research paper](http://zola.di.unipi.it/rossano/wp-content/papercite-data/pdf/cpm12.pdf).  Short of indexing your entire dictionary, at the very least this might suggest a search heuristic that you can use.

Answer (score 3):

I have done this myself and used it to create a (not very good) Windows game.

I used the approach recommended by others of implementing this as a graph, where each node is a word and they are connected if they differ in one letter. This means you can use well known graph theory results to find paths between words (eg simple recursion where knowing the words at distance 1 allows you to find the words at distance 2).

The tricky part is building up the graph. The bad news is that it is O(n^2). The good news is that it doesn't have to be done in real time - rather than your program reading the dictionary words from a file, it reads in the data structure you baked earlier.

The key insight is that the order doesn't matter, in fact it gets in the way. You need to construct another form in which to hold the words which strips out the order information and allows words to be compared more easily. You can do this in O(n). You have lots of choices; I will show two.

1. For word puzzles I quit often use an encoding which I call anagram dictionary. A word is represented by another word which has the same letters but in alphabetic sequence. So "cars" becomes "acrs". Both lists and slits become "ilsst". This is a better structure for comparison than the original word, but much better comparisons exist (however, it is a very useful structure for other word puzzles).
2. Letter counts. An array of 26 values which show the frequency of that letter in the word. So for "cars" it starts 1,0,1,0,0... as there is one "a" and one "c". Hold an external list of the non-zero entries (which letters appear in the word) so you only have to check 5 or 6 values at most instead of 26. Very simple to compare two words held in this form quickly by ensuring at most two counts are different. This is the one I would use.

So, this is how I did it.

I wrote a program which implemented the data structure up above.

It had a class called WordNode. This contains the original word; a List of all other WordNodes which are one letter different; an array of 26 integers giving the frequency of each letter, a list of the non-zero values in the letter count array.

The initialiser populates the letter frequency array and the corresponding list of non-zero values. It sets the list of connected WordNodes to zero.

After I have created an instance of the WordNode class for every word, I run a compare method which checks to see if the frequency counts are different in no more than two places. That normally takes slightly less compares than there are letters in the words; not too bad. If they are different in exactly two places they differ by one letter, and I add that WordNode into the list of WordNodes differing in only one letter.

This means we now have a graph of all the words one letter different.

You can export either the whole data structure or strip out the letter frequency and other stuff you don't need and save it (I used serialized XML. If you go that way, make sure you check it handles the List of WordNodes as references and not embedded objects).

Your actual game then only has to read in this data structure (instead of a dictionary) and it can find the words one letter different with a direct lookup, in essentially zero time.

Pity my game was crap.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest (recursive) algorithm is I can think of (well, the only one I can think in the moment) is

- Initialize a empty blacklist
- Take all words from your dictionary that is a valid step for the current word
- remove the ones that are in the blacklist
- Check if you can find the target word.

  - if not, repeat the algorithm for all words you found in last step
  - if yes, you found it. Return the recursion printing all words in the path you found.

Maybe someone with a bit more time can add the ruby code for this?

Comment: I wasn't really looking for an implementation, I can do that on my own. I was just having trouble getting started. Thanks, this was really useful.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
x = 'hate'
puts x = x.next until x == 'love'
```

And if you couple it with dictionary lookup, you will get a list of all valid words in between in that dictionary.

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding the problem. If it was just all words in a literal dictionary between `hate` and `love` this would be trivial. It isn't though.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I skimmed your question too quickly.